# how do I turn off access control and allow all users to see all contacts?

Tags: contacts

When we started setting up civicrm many months ago we applied access controls so that users wouldn't see any contacts until we add them to their particular group. Over time we've come to the conclusion that there are too many situations where we need to see each other's contacts, so I've been requested to undo the access controls and leave it more wide open. What is the cleanest way to make this transition?

Comment: can you explain why just deleting the ACLs won't achieve what you want? also, if you do want nuanced access have you considered the Permissioned Relationships approach https://fuzion.co.nz/relationship-permissions-acls

Answer (score 1):

There is a permission in the CMS (Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla) called "CiviCRM: View all contacts". Give this permission to any role/user that is supposed to see contacts in CiviCRM.